# find -exec grep does not work

Tags: ssh, find, grep

I need to use a find command in a script with ssh and grep together.
Something like this:

`ssh user@host find /var/log -type f -mtime 1 -exec grep -i -F error warn {} \;`

But it says, that there is no argument for -exec.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the commands inside quotes:

```
ssh user@host "find /var/log -type f -mtime 1 -exec grep -i -F error warn {} \;"
```

or

```
ssh user@host 'find /var/log -type f -mtime 1 -exec grep -i -F error warn {} \;'
```